How do I collect the CPU info of the application in OTEL implementations using Go SDK?
I am implementing OTEL instrumention in our application. I need to view the CPU usage, but the given runtime info only provides the memory info not the CPU. How can we get this?
runtime.Start(runtime.WithMeterProvider(meterProvider),runtime.WithMinimumReadMemStatsInterval(time.Second))

Here this runtime.Start provides the memory related information of the pod, how to get the CPU info here?
runtime.go.cgo.calls         -          Number of cgo calls made by the current process
runtime.go.gc.count          -          Number of completed garbage collection cycles
runtime.go.gc.pause_ns       (ns)       Amount of nanoseconds in GC stop-the-world pauses
runtime.go.gc.pause_total_ns (ns)       Cumulative nanoseconds in GC stop-the-world pauses since the program started
runtime.go.goroutines        -          Number of goroutines that currently exist
runtime.go.lookups           -          Number of pointer lookups performed by the runtime
runtime.go.mem.heap_alloc    (bytes)    Bytes of allocated heap objects
runtime.go.mem.heap_idle     (bytes)    Bytes in idle (unused) spans
runtime.go.mem.heap_inuse    (bytes)    Bytes in in-use spans
runtime.go.mem.heap_objects  -          Number of allocated heap objects
runtime.go.mem.heap_released (bytes)    Bytes of idle spans whose physical memory has been returned to the OS
runtime.go.mem.heap_sys      (bytes)    Bytes of heap memory obtained from the OS
runtime.go.mem.live_objects  -          Number of live objects is the number of cumulative Mallocs - Frees
runtime.uptime               (ms)       Milliseconds since application was initialized


For instance, you can use https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil

@kostix Thanks...
Will this helps to include System Info to the Newrelic ? Do i need to include this as part of setSDK ? or for every request ?
_, cpuError := cpu.InfoWithContext(ctx)
 if cpuError != nil {
  slog.ErrorContext(ctx, "cpu info provider Error", slog.Any("error", cpuError))
  return err
 }


I do not quite parse what you're asking for. What I suggested to look at, is a package which can be used to query CPU usage of the process which is requesting this information. How exactly to make this information available to "Newrelic" (whatever this means), I do not know. Supposedly by creating and periodically updating some metric to be picked by by OTEL, but I do not really know.
